# In Chrome, how can I render Unicode block characters without gaps?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I need to display data containing Unicode full block characters (\u2588). However, as you can see here, browsers seem to apply font smoothing to the blocks causing gaps to appear between the blocks. ██████████████

How can I render these characters without the gaps?

I tried using CSS 'line-spacing' with a negative value as a hack, but this text is being rendered with a mono-space typeface and it throws off alignment with the rest of the content.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it isn't universal. In my Firefox/54 x64 Windows 10 I see a single black rectangle.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be just Chrome. I'll update the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use font shadow to fill the gap. I know its a hack but unless you plan to overlap the characters by positioning them in a fixed orientation I don't see how this can be achieved across different browsers.

```
text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

Example:

```css
body {
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
 ██████████████
```

Another option is to pad the characters within a container and set the background color the same as the font color. Example:

```css
#container {
  background: black;
  color: black;
  width: 159px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
 ██████████████
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for a long time and still searching for a perfect solution. CSS text-shadow method by Kieran Devlin is good, but only for cases when there is only one-line blocks with same color.

I can suggest this solution via JavaScript (or just CSS) tho this is not 100% perfect. Here we just making sure that user is on Chromium and then squashing blocks together into each other, therefore filling the gaps. After that, we can use transform scale to return initial size and transform translateX to return it to it's initial position.

```
if (window.chrome) {
    art_div.css({
        'letter-spacing': '-0.1em',
        'line-height': '1.2em',
        'transform': 'scale(1.2, 1) translateX(8%)'
    });
}
```

You can see it visualized in [my GitHub issue](https://github.com/hermanTenuki/ASCII-Generator.site/issues/9), maybe i will find something better.